# Подключение к phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html

Не получается сделать подключение к серверу. Данные вводятся, но на phpmyadmin не остаются.Использую openserver, настройки стандартные. Пикрил с phpmyadmin (в таблице пусто). Что не так делаю?[image: пикрил].

```
            <?php
    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var(trim($_POST['password']),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST['email']),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    //$age = filter_var(trim($_POST['age_year']),
    //FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if(mb_strlen($login) < 4 || mb_strlen($login) > 15) {
    echo "Логин должен быть не менее 4 символов и не более 15!";
    exit();
    } else if(mb_strlen($password) < 4 || mb_strlen($password) > 15) {
    echo "Пароль должен быть не менее 4 символов и не более 15!";
    exit();
    }

    $mysql = new mysqli('18thuniverse', 'mysql', 'mysql', 'register-bd');
    $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`, `email`) VALUES('$login', '$password', '$email')");
    $mysql->close();
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="register.css">
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>18th Universe - Регистрация</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      Регистрация
      <div class="main">
      <form action="check.php" method="POST">
        <p><input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="Имя" autofocus required></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль" required autofocus></p> 
        <p><input type="password" name="Repassword" placeholder="Повторите пароль" required autofocus></p> 
        <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="18thUniverse@gmail.com" required> 
        <p><input type="text" name="age_year" id="age_year" list="age" placeholder="Возраст" required autofocus>
         <datalist id="age">
           <option value="1">
           <option value="2">
           <option value="3">
           <option value="4">
           <option value="5">
           <option value="6">
           <option value="7">
           <option value="8">
           <option value="9">
           <option value="10">
           <option value="11">
           <option value="12">
           <option value="13">
           <option value="14">
           <option value="15">
           <option value="16">
           <option value="17">
           <option value="18">
           <option value="19">
           <option value="20">
           <option value="21">
           <option value="22">
           <option value="23">
           <option value="24">
           <option value="25">
           <option value="26">
           <option value="27">
           <option value="28">
           <option value="29">
           <option value="30">
           <option value="31">
           <option value="32">
           <option value="33">
           <option value="34">
           <option value="35">
           <option value="36">
           <option value="37">
           <option value="38">
           <option value="39">
           <option value="40">
           <option value="41">
           <option value="42">
         <option value="43">
         <option value="44">
         <option value="45">
         <option value="46">
         <option value="47">
         <option value="48">
         <option value="49">
         <option value="50">
         <option value="51">
         <option value="52">
         <option value="53">
         <option value="54">
         </datalist>
       </p>
       <p class="me"><button class="btn reg-success" type="submit">Зарегестрироваться</button></p>
       </div>
      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: а если после insert'а сделать select на эти же самые значения, они будут получены?

Comment: Вы можете использовать `echo($mysql->error);` для того, чтобы увидеть ошибку. Возможно, ошибка возникает при подключении к базе данных - попробуйте использовать `echo($mysql->connect_error);` для того, чтобы увидеть ошибку подключения.

P.S.: Не могу не предупредить Вас, что текущий метод работы с базой данных ставит всю систему под угрозы SQL Injection. Используйте [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES('Ryuk', '12345', 'lo2@gmail.com')' at line 1